# Latitude and longitude lines for Pluto and Charon

Tags: pluto, mapping, charon, coordinates

I am hoping someone can point me to images of Pluto and Charon with latitude and longitude lines.

I know it's the convention to designate the near point of a tidelocked moon as 0°, 0°. Is the same true of a planet tidelocked with his moon?

I am doing some drawings of the Pluto Charon neighborhood. For example:

[image]

The drawings would be more interesting and informative if the Pluto and Charon circles included some features. I am hoping a lobe of Pluto's heart is close to the near point.

Comment: See http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2013/07301442-plutosci-zangari-cartography.html

Comment: I posted some global map for Pluto images [here](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/10311/49) but mind that ambiguity about South and North poles. The high resolution image has a grid, and its values are shown in the smaller resolution one, if they're even correct. :O Also see [Is there a system for choosing the Prime Meridian on a given body/world?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5600/49)

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any particular standard for the primary body, however for the Pluto system, in this image the 0,0 point is on the opposite side of the hearth:
[image]
And in this image, the hearth is shown to also be at the opposite side from Charon.
[image] 
So I assume you are right.